# How to align cell content (InlineShape) to the right?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I am using C# to programmatically create a word document (Office 16.0 Interop).

In the header section of the document I added a table of which one cell contains a picture. However, I can't get the picture to align to the right within the cell. It is left aligned by default (as it should be).

Oddly enough, cells have a `VerticalAlignment` property of type `WdCellVerticalAlignment` but seem to lack a property for horizontal alignment.

How can I align an InlineShape within a cell to the **right**?

[image: example with left-aligned InlineShape in cell]

Comment: How about `cell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.wdAlignParagraphRight`?

Comment: Wow, I looked for paragraph options only on the `Cell` itself, not on its `Range`. It worked, thank you. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple once you know the object you are trying to align:

```
cell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.wdAlignParagraphRight
```