# Word, How paste letter or symbol in end of cell?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using Word interop in C# app, How paste letter or symbol in end of empty cell?

```
Cell.Range.Text="  *"
```

It should look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XSsa.png

Comment: Try `Cell.Range.Text += " *";`

Comment: Cell doesn't content text.

Comment: Do you look for horizontal alignment? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079674/how-to-align-cell-content-inlineshape-to-the-right